# How can I fetch the sites or subsites from a site collection and export them to excel document?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, fetch, export, sites

I've been trying to fetch the subsites from a site collection and export them into excel document, and I've been checking different scripts and testing to get a special one which could help me to get this information, even though none of them have work.

I've tested these two:

https://sposcripts.com/get-all-sites-and-subsites/
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300136/how-can-i-get-all-site-collections-and-sub-sites-inside-a-powershell-script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIKe7.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Both scripts connect to the site.  So you need to run as an Admin.  Where does the scripts fail?  To debug powershell scripts I add statements to output variables so I know where the script stops working.  Usually use $variable | Format-Table

Answer (score 0):

You may need to -UseWebLogin to sign in the MFA enabled account. Try using this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -UseWebLogin
```

OR

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -PnPManagementShell -LaunchBrowser
```